# Linq to DataGridView and back to KeyValuePair (or similar)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have the following code to populate a DataGridView

```
        var results = from loc in dtLocations.AsEnumerable()
                      join con in dtContacts.AsEnumerable() on (int)loc["contactid"] equals (int)con["id"]
                      select new
                      {
                          id = con["id"],
                          mpoc = loc["mpoc"],
                          directno = loc["directno"],
                          extension = loc["extension"],
                          faxno = loc["faxno"],
                          billing = con["billing"],
                          fullname = con["fullname"],
                          mobno = con["mobno"],
                          email = con["email"]
                      };

        dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgv.DataSource = results.ToList<object>();
```

But I cant read it back in when I click a cell

```
    private void dgvLocations_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
        ????? vals = ((List<object>)dgv.DataSource)[e.RowIndex];
        object id = vals.id;  //errors of course
    }
```

I can see in the Watcher panel of Visual Studio that it can determine the elements in the List, but I cant figure out the type that I need to set vals to in order to read them back again :(

[image]

Comment: It is an anonymous type. It *cannot* be expressed in a static type (other than when it was introduced). Use a named (non-anonymous) type or `dynamic` or (even ickier, `object` and explicit reflection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It (`new { .. }`) introduces an [*anonymous type*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx). Anonymous types *cannot* be specified by a statically-known ("compile time") name.

Use a named (non-anonymous) type (where `MyRow` is an already defined class with the required properties):

```
// Put data in non-anonymous type
select new MyRow {
   id = ..,
}

// Now can use a name statically
MyRow row = (MyRow)data[rowIndex];
```

Also the [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) type can be used with C#/.NET4+. Or, even ickier, `object` and explicit reflection. (Note that `dynamic`-typed expressions effectively handle the icky reflection automatically; just as with `object`,  static typing information is still lost.)

Comment: Hi Pst. can you please elaborate on the `dynamic` or point me to some further reading? Much appreciated!

Comment: @Christian Added a reference (and fixed the nonsense overwrites :-/)